# OpenJDK 8 support period in Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, java, security, openjdk, support

According to the [Ubuntu releases page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS has support until 2023 and the end of life is 2028. What does this mean for the [OpenJDK 8 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-8&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all)?

How long will security updates be available for OpenJDK 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Results of the command `ubuntu-support-status --show-supported` show that openjdk-8-jdk is supported until April 2021 (Community - 3y). To show the same results in a more easily navigable form run `ubuntu-support-status --show-supported | less` and scroll down with the mouse to the openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-8-jre support status. In Ubuntu 20.04 and later `ubuntu-support-status` has been replace by `ubuntu-security-status` which does not have a `--show-supported` option.

openjdk-11-jdk and openjdk-11-jre are supported until April 2023 (Canonical - 5y).